# Use HBase API Table interface can't put data into table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

There had a interesting problem when I put data into HBase table. In the past time the code can running well without any problem. But now it can't execute normal. There had throws a strange problem in below code line:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Test HBase Java API functions
 *
 * @author elkan1788
 */
public class HBaseAPITest {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HBaseAPITest.class);

private Connection connect;

private byte[] family = Bytes.toBytes("lg");

@BeforeClass
public void init() throws Exception {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "master01.office.sao.so,cluster02.office.sao.so");

    connect = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
}

@Test
public void testPutRecord() throws Exception {

    byte[] rowKey = Bytes.toBytes(Long.toHexString(new Date().getTime()));
    byte[] ts = Bytes.toBytes("ts");
    byte[] c = Bytes.toBytes("c");
    byte[] oip = Bytes.toBytes("oip");

    logger.info("Start HBase Put method test...");

    Put put = new Put(rowKey);
    put.addColumn(family, ts, Bytes.toBytes("2017-01-11"));
    put.addColumn(family, c, Bytes.toBytes(1024));
    put.addColumn(family, oip, Bytes.toBytes("127.0.0.1"));

 //        HTable table = new HTable(connect.getConfiguration(), "test");
    Table table = connect.getTable(TableName.valueOf("test"));
    logger.info("Connect table success.");
    logger.info("{}", table.getName().getNameAsString());
    logger.info("{}", table.getConfiguration().toString());
    table.put(put);
    table.close();

    logger.info("End HBase Put method test...");
}

@AfterClass
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    connect.close();
}
}
```

It were wait for a long while on `table.put(put)`,  but now throw any exception. I had try get help from search engine and no any response. Someone said maybe you `hbase client` version not match the HBase version. Then I try use them under same version but still can not into data.

After do some try I had out put the DEBUG info on console, it output message like those:

```
18:48:36.908 [main-SendThread(master01.office.sao.so:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x2599208a32c0260, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 8,4  replyHeader:: 8,38654779738,0  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response:: #ffffffff0001a726567696f6e7365727665723a3136303230cffffffeacffffff931c23ffffffedffffff8f50425546a15a9636c7573746572303210ffffff947d18ffffffa8ffffff95ffffffe0ffffffb6ffffff992b100183,s{38654771300,38654771300,1484294512812,1484294512812,0,0,0,0,62,0,38654771300}
```

Also I had try use hbase shell command execute put function, it can work well. My HBase version is `1.1.2.2.5.3.0-37, rcb8c969d1089f1a34e9df11b6eeb96e69bcf878d, Tue Nov 29 18:48:22 UTC 2016`.

So what's wrong with this HBase service? How can I fixed it.

There were the HBase configure settings: [hbase-config](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2icHTcsD-zHcTNLTUk3NW81cm8)

Comment: you mean from shell put is working and from java client its not isnt it? if so can you paste your code details and complete stack of exception you got? with out that its very difficult to answer this.

Comment: Thanks. I had update the complete code and HBase config file in problem description. Also I don't think it's code issue, because in the past time it can run well. But I can point out what's wrong so need someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTable instead of Table. May be your issue can be solved.

Comment: Not this issue HTable were past API.